# Magento2 Integration with Klaviyo "Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later." issue

Tags: integration, magento2

I use Magento2 ver. 2.4.2

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. I Login in Magento2 with admin credentials.
2. In Magento2 administration, Stores -> Configuration -> Klaviyo is properly set, and I see the Klaviyo lists there in the dropdown list.
3. When I go to Magento administration, System -> Integrations and click "Add new integration",

- I set name, my e-mail,
- I set Callback url: https://www.klaviyo.com/integration-oauth-one/magento-two/auth/confirm?c=XXXXXXX
- I set Identity link URL: https://www.klaviyo.com/integration-oauth-one/magento-two/auth/handle
- I set my Magento2 admin pass
- Go to API tab and in Resource Access dropdown list I set "All", and
- Click "Save", it is being saved, with note that the data are saved, but the new user is not created, because the old one is overwritten and updated.

**Expected result:**
When I go to Magento2 in System -> Integrations and click on "Activate", I expect activated integration, so that I can finish integration in Klaviyo.

**Actual result:**
When I go to Magento2 in System -> Integrations and click on "Activate", I get the window with note "The integration you selected asks you to approve access to the following:" and all the selected resources are listed. I click on "Allow" window and I get "Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.".
When I go to see the integration, what I see is that "Consumer Key" and "Consumer Secret" fields are filled, but "Access Token" and "Access Token Secret" are empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in the core of Magento, see: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/32542

It should already be fixed with the following pull request https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/32095 but I believe it's currently not in a release version. But ou should be able to [create a patch](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/patching.html) from this PR.

It's also possible to create an 'ugly' fix in de vendor directory by applying the changes from this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/339413/45764 (this is not recommended)